# Reduce CPU usage when downscaling HD>SD>Low on the same codec (H264)

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtmp

I'm using ffmpeg over 3 years now mainly I'm doing live broadcasting on my site , currently I'm preparing to do 5 livebroadcast on the same time using my VPS server `CPU E3-1240 v5` `OpenVZ` Since I'm only allowed to use 1 vCore CPU usage jumps high very fast . What I ask , I know H264 algorithm based on calculation of previous frame (ref frame) and I frame So I tried -copyinkf and -break_non_keyframes 1 with no effect on the speed BTW here is my main broadcast command :-

```
ffmpeg -re -i "http://sorce.m3u " -s 720x406 -r 23.976 -vcodec libx264  -profile:v high444  \ 
-crf 35 -copyinkf - break_non_keyframes 1 -preset slow -acodec libfdk_aac \
-profile:a aac_he_v2 -b:a 8k -map_metadata -1 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/live
```

Current I use `-preset slow` to improve image quality little bit CPU usage `60%` even with `preset fast` CPU usage were `47%` -preset veryfast CPU-usage `35%`

Comment: What's wrong with the faster presets?

Comment: it's peak the CPU usage sometime goes up `50%` which will kill the tow process , and their is huge quality drop, this setting is the lowest I can get for ~`265kbps`broadcast ,,+ I test it without the extra `-copyinkf` flags with no different at all , BTW I'm using `crf` method with value of  `35`

Comment: There is no way to use less CPU without reducing quality. If there was, that setting would be turned on by default.

Comment: I'm using low pic size `720x406` with low bitrate , on my laptop cpu its run it fast , but the server VPS limited to 1 vCore so my code above will uses more cpu resources .

Comment: Alright I found out what's was peak CPU usage `-profile:v high444` once I remove it the cpu usage drooped dramatically to less  then `30%`